# How do I add framework assemblies in Azure Function

Tags: azure, .net-assembly, azure-functions

I need to add System.Web.Script.Serialization and System.Web.Extensions to my function app so that I can deserialize json string using the following code :

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>("{ \"test\":\"some data\" }");
string test= item["test"];
```

This does not work :

```
#r "System.Web.Script.Serialization"
#r "System.Web.Extensions"
```

How do I add resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial reference likely failed because you were trying to add an assembly reference to `System.Web.Script.Serialization`, which is a namespace. Adding a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` should work, but using Json.NET is recommended anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I can't get that work, so I ended up using Newtonsoft Json serializer/deserializer. What you need to do is, follow [this instruction](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference/#fileupdate) to upload project.json file to your function app with this content -

```
{
   "frameworks": {
   "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
          "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
      }
   }
  }
}
```

This basically creates dependency. Then add this name space to your code :  "using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq". Voila, you can convert your json string to object like this :

```
dynamic item = JObject.Parse("{number:1000}");
log.Info($"My number is: {item.number}");
```